# Difference between "spicy" and "hot"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, synonyms

I make a distinction between "hot" and "spicy" food ("hot" not referring to temperature). I consider "hot" food the kind that "burns" and "spicy" food that has lots of flavor, but that may or may not "burn", but has some "heat" to it and is flavorful.

I've been told that there is no real difference between the two and that I'm crazy for thinking that Tabasco sauce makes something "hot", while something like curry, ginger, or cumin makes something "spicy". Please help me out a little here with a little clarification.

Comment: Readers of this thread might well find this thread from cooking.SE approaching the topic from the other angle to be of some interest: [Is wasabi considered to be spicy or to be a spice?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/27532)

Comment: as an anecdote, Hebrew has very specific words to describe each and every one of them without having ambiguity like English. חם - hot in temperature, חריף - has the feeling of burning, מטובל - seasoned, spicy, not necessary the rest. English really makes the life hard in this case.

Comment: I'd like to point out that every english speaker I know uses spicy and hot completely interchangeably. For "spicy" things in the sense that you use it we say well-seasoned.

Comment: Heh, if we are throwing anecdotes, Portuguese also has separate words for hot-as-in-temperature (_quente_), hot-as-in-flavoured-spicy (_temperado_) and hot-as-in-stingy-and-makes-you-red-and-sweaty (_apimentado_) - the later one being literary "peppered"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I (and this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spicy)) recommend the use of the of the word *piquance* (or *piquancy*) to describe the condition of something being *spicy hot*, such as chili peppers.

The article explains:

> A pumpkin pie can be both *hot* (out of the oven) and
>   *spicy* (due to the common inclusion of ingredients in its recipe such as cinnamon, nutmeg, allspice, mace and cloves) but is not actually
>   *piquant*. Conversely, pure capsaicin is piquant, yet is not naturally accompanied by a hot temperature or spices.

To avoid ambiguity:

- Use *piquant* [**pee**-kuhnt, or pee-**kahnt**] to describe something that is spicy hot. (The [Scoville scale](http://www.chilipepper.com/TheScovilleScale/tabid/59/Default.aspx) measures the piquance of chili peppers according to the amount of capsaicin they contain.)
- Use *spicy* to describe something having the quality, flavor, or fragrance of spice. (Many curries are spicy without being piquant.)
- Reserve *hot* to describe the temperature of something.

Comment: Wikipedia - is there anything it doesn't know? Thanks for the awesome answer. I have a new fancy word to both expand my vocabulary and annoy the common person.

Comment: You're welcome. As always, the mechanisms of voting on this site are a mystery to me.

Comment: Though OP might want to note that virtually no one (other than perhaps a restaurant critic or cookbook author) would describe a seriously spicy dish as *piquant*.

Comment: +1 onomatomaniak. My Pocket OED defines piquant as "agreeably pungent, stimulating".  I doubt anyone would apply that to a Thai red curry or a phal.  "Hot ..(of pepper &c.) pungent" - note the lack of "agreeably".  Note also that Scoville gives Scoville Heat Units so that rather argues against the wikipedia article.

Comment: @onomatomaniak: Dunno; ever heard of _salsa picante_? And when I'm cooking, this exchange from STV oftens pops into my head: NEELIX: Here we are Mister Tuvok, one bowl of authentic Vulcan plomeek soup. TUVOK: It is rather (cough) piquant.

Comment: @Wudang: Yes, but note that articles about the Scoville scale always qualify that it measures the _spicy heat_ or _piquant heat_. Also, the OP was told that there was **no** difference between _hot_ and _spicy_, which isn't so.

Comment: @Wudang - Speaking of which, I've heard serious spice-fanatics call a particularly hot dish "Scovillian".

Comment: @sarah: (Sorry, let's try again.) Are you down-voting based on an entry in a single dictionary? (Especially from a sense of [hot](http://www.wordnik.com/words/hot) that ranks no higher than fourth in most dictionaries?) I suggested the use of _piquant_ precisely to disambiguate  _spicy hot_ from, say, _piping hot_.

Comment: :) I'm not sure using *piquant* _does_ eliminate the ambiguity, because in several definitions Scoville scale heat isn't a given. For instance: _Pleasantly pungent or tart in taste; *spicy*_ and _stimulating to the taste; *giving zest*; tart; sharp; pungent_ from: http://www.wordnik.com/words/piquant. Also, synonyms for piquant include *highly-seasoned*, *savory*, *spicy*, tangy, tart, well-flavored, and zesty here:http://thesaurus.com/browse/piquant. As a _spicy_ food lover, but a wimp about _hot_ food, this is a question I might have asked, so I'm hoping for a definitive answer.

Comment: @sarah: Perhaps [this entry](http://www.blog.curried.com/index.php/2011/08/hot-spicy/) in Curried.com's blog has the answer you seek?

Comment: @Gnawme Thanks for the Curried link. (Despite this: _the *word* that describes it best *is called* piquancy._) Answer & comment up-voted with hopes that this distinction will become more prevalent, and I'll no longer get my taste buds cauterized by _hot_ food misleadingly described as merely _spicy_.

Comment: This is a very misleading answer which does not reflect current general usage. The linked Wikipedia article is using piquant according to a fairly technical definition which would only be used by food experts (presumably the author of the article falls into this category). As an native English speaker and regular curry connoisseur in London, I can guarantee that if you follow the recommendation in this answer you will just end up confusing everyone.

Comment: @mikera Lest you forget, I'm answering the OP, who was told that there is _no_ difference between _spicy_ and _hot_, which is patently untrue. As someone who not only cooks curries (most of which are spicy), but Southwestern and Thai dishes as well (many of which are distinctly piquant), I find "general usage" inadequate. When a friend of mine bites into my black pepper chicken (made with a healthy helping of Thai bird chilies) and exclaims, "Ooh, that's spicy!" I say, "No, dear, it's piquant. My coconut curry is spicy; here, taste the difference..."

Comment: There's an episode of Star Trek Voyager in which Tuvok remarks that the plomeek soup (prepared by a Talaxian) was unpalatably piquant. (http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Talax-ilzay). If only humans had a comparable grasp on their own language as a Vulcan. From http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/113.htm: TUVOK: It is rather (cough) piquant.
NEELIX: It is zesty, isn't it. I tried following the recipe in the computer's databank but it seemed so bland, so I took the liberty of spicing it up a bit. Call it plomeek soup a la Neelix.

Comment: @rajah9 Yes, that scene always comes to mind when I hear or use the word _piquant_.

Comment: That Wikipedia article doesn't (perhaps no longer, haven't checked) recommend the use of *piquancy* for Scoville type hotness. In fact they explain that the word would not apply to a chilly on its own. They also explain that the word *can*, in fact apply to a flavoursome tomato. And it cannot apply to something uncomfortable. My main niggle, however, is that reserving *hot* to refer to temperature doesn't reduce any ambiguity, because other people also use *hot* to refer to Scoville type heat. Readers or listeners will have no idea about your personal style predilections. Why should they?

Answer (score 5):

Merriam-Webster defines *[spicy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spicy)* as having the quality, flavour or fragrance of spice. OALD defines *[spicy](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/spicy)* as having a strong taste because spices have been used to flavour it. CALD defines *[spicy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/spicy_1)* as containing strong flavours from spices.

If we use these definitions then *spicy* food may or may not be *hot*, depending on the particular spices being used. Having said that, because many spices are hot, *spicy* is considered almost synonymous with *hot*. Therefore, there is a difference between the two but it is slight.

Comment: Right. A slight difference, and almost synonymous - but not the same thing. Research on some culinary sites said basically the same thing. Score one for Dopyiii.

Comment: Restaurants have skewed *spicy* towards "peppery", but not many of us would describe [Bhut Jolokia chili pepper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhut_Jolokia_chili_pepper) as *really spicy*. We'd call it *"Really [your expletive] hot!"* And a glass of pungenty-flavoured mulled wine would be *really spicy*, rather than *hot* (unless the actual serving temperature was a bit excessive).

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to food there is that slight distinction but think about: We are hosting the "spicy" dancers from Spain. vs We are hosting the "hot" dancers from Spain.
Now,there is big difference, isn't there?

Answer (score 0):

*Spices* are the something visible, *spicy* is where those things are used. *Hotness* is the effect of those things. and you know spices are always hot. You can make it less hot by adding less spice. So it's a synonym but spice is something tangible, while hotness is not tangible. I think.

Comment: Spices are not always hot. For example, vanilla and cinnamon.

Comment: Hugo, that's a good point.