# How to say that food is hot (temperature) without the listener thinking that I mean "spicy"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, ambiguity

There is an excellent discussion of spicy vs. hot at [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50080/difference-between-spicy-and-hot).

However, having read it, I did not see any answer that tells how to say unambiguously that food is hot (temperature) without being misunderstood.

If I say that my food is *spicy*, a listener will unambiguously understand that I am referring to the sensation associated with eating.

However, I can't think of a good way to say that my food is hot (temperature) without a listener possibly thinking that I mean spicy.

In the referenced question, a poster described how to unambiguously say that food is spicy.  How can I unambiguously say that food is *hot*?

Comment: @Em1, there are lots of people who don't reserve "hot" for that usage, though.

Comment: Off topic: do other languages use the same word for this, too?  If not (attempted on topic) and you and your listener both know that other language, use it.  "Watch out --- *caliente!*"

Comment: @GEdgar In Germany definitively unambiguously.

Comment: Without the context most of the words would be ambiguous.

Comment: @Em1: That only works if all participants in the discussion follow the same convention. For, say, a cook book, you could establish this rule up front. But if, say, you are having dinner with friends and you point to a plate and say,  "That's really hot", no one else necessarily knows that this is the convention you're using.

Comment: I find myself using extra words, like "This is really hot ... I mean in temperature, not spicy." Which of course is very awkward. I'll be interested to see if someone comes up with a concise way to say it.

Comment: @Jay Of course, you're absolutely right. But there is something more, I just want to mention: What's about gesture and facial expressions. (e.g. wagging with my fingers in front of my face - however this gesture is called). Just to point out: There are more than just words. But finally: Your point is absolutely passable.

Comment: @GEdgar In French we use for "spicy" the word "fort", which is "strong".

Comment: @GEdgar in German, it's "scharf", which means "sharp". So as long as you don't serve a dish containing blades, it's pretty unambiguous. It's noteworthy though that, as with the French "fort", there's no word meaning only "spicy", i.e. without describing something different in other contexts.

Comment: @Jan how do they describe sharp cheddar cheese?

Comment: @Random832 Well, a sharp taste in German is usually “säuerlich” (= acerbic). But in the context of cheese, I would rarely use “sharp”, I’d use “spicy” (and accordingly “scharf” or “pikant” in German).

Comment: @Jan: ... and then someone serves a dish made with pineapple that had some of the skin left on, and you say, "Hey, there's something sharp in this food!" and everyone thinks you mean spicy ....

Comment: @Jay: they absolutely would :-)

Comment: Having either lots of different spices, or a high amount of one spice, has nothing in particular to do with that food item happens to piquant. Not all spices burn; most, in fact, do not.

Comment: I think @Timothy Jones had the best answer: "Hot to the touch.", and the piquant version is "Hot to taste."

Comment: [Related](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVgMHKTSUtM)

Comment: "The food is high in average thermal energy"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's a genuine inadequacy in English vocabulary, with no simple fix:

- "Hot" is ambiguous
- "Spicy" is also ambiguous (certain kinds of cake, for example, are spicy but not hot)
- "Piquant" is not frequently used, so could seem pretentious.

You must therefore keep an eye on context, and add information where necessary.

Most of the time, when talking about food, "hot" refers to temperature, *except* in the context of mustard, horseradish, and non-Northern-European cuisines. So unless you have explicitly established that those foodstuffs are in-scope, it's pretty safe to assume that "hot" refers to temperature.

Comment: "Spicy" is also more general in meaning than "piquant".

Comment: @MetaEd isn't that the essence of my second bullet?

Comment: Yes. I misread your answer.

Comment: Well sure, if someone says, "This turkey is very hot" I would likely assume they meant temperature, but if they said, "These chili peppers are very hot" I would assume they meant spicy. The problem comes when you are trying to say that the turkey is spicy or the chili peppers have high temperature.

Comment: English is bad for this.  Spanish is good: *caliente ≠ picante ≠ con muchas especias.*  When you mean piquant, say it. Don’t pussyfoot around.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/798/

Comment: @slim Your last paragraph is untrue in an part of the English-speaking world where spicy-hot food is the norm or at least very common, which is a whole lot of places.

Comment: With 50 votes and 2500 views and no clear answer, I'm going to accept this answer that it is "a genuine inadequacy in the English vocabulary with no simple fix."

Comment: @RiceFlourCookies You didn't like Lunivore's addition of an adjective to the phrase?

Answer (score 103):

You could use this idiom:

> That food is piping hot.

There's some information about the origin of the phrase [here](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/piping-hot.html).

Comment: "Steaming hot" also works to describe food that has a high temperature. But "Flaming hot" usually refers to taste rather than temperature.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Unless it's Crepe Suzette.  Or Christmas Pudding.

Comment: @z7sgѪ: True... I have friends who acutally say "thermally hot" and "hot-tasting" to disambiguate "hot", but they're engineers - I know most people don't talk this way. ;)

Comment: How about "scalding" or "scalding hot"?

Comment: "Scalding hot" has connotations of danger. I guess you could use it if you wanted people to be wary. I like "piping hot" because if I was eating hot food, that's the heat I'd like it to be.

Comment: This answer is immediately, obviously correct. Why? Why is it clear that "piping" indicates thermal and not gustatory temperature?

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens It comes from the noise that the steam makes as it escapes from the food. That doesn't happen just because it's spicy-hot (even though it might make you feel like it's escaping from you!)

Comment: Scald also implies _liquid_ which might or might not be helpful in context.

Comment: I can't see why this answer hasn't been chosen as the accepted one. It's a good expression.

Comment: @Neeku, thanks for the support. While the idiom I provided *could* be used, it's a bit archaic. Slim's guidance is pragmatic and deserves the tick. Mine is perhaps more entertaining or enlightening, but I am very happy with the upvotes I've been given. Originally when his was marked I think we had very similar vote counts.

Comment: @Lunivore Hmmm... Ok! I'm very happy with the word "pipping", and it's already stuck in my mind now, so I don't even want to think of any other alternative at all! :D

Comment: @Neeku Piping. Rhymes with wiping. "Pipping" means to pip; either to remove the pips or to beat someone narrowly at a game.

Comment: @Lunivore OMG! This is pure telepathy! So I was trying to use the word this evening while cooking something *sizzling* on the stove, and I said it's *pipping*, feeling so happy that now I know this word! But no! I was corrected by my husband, being said that it's *piping* not *pipping*. Then I came at my laptop and noticed this comment here! Such a shame! I want it pronounced that way! :D

Answer (score 71):

You can describe what's making it hot, e.g. "Be careful, that just came out of the oven".

Or, suggested by @onomatomaniak in a comment, "better let this cool down a little".

Comment: +1 A good suggestion. You could also say something like "I better let this cool down a little."

Comment: I kind of prefer @onomatomaniak's suggestion as it actually describes the temperature. Saying something just came out of the oven wouldn't give me enough of a hint.

Comment: True. When you know that something you say may have ambiguous meaning, it is best to use alternative ways to express it. If "..came out of the oven" isn't good enough, use "Careful, you may burn your tongue." Or what @onomatomaniak said.

Comment: @onomatomaniak, I edited to add your (popular!) suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Probably influenced by the fact that my oven's broken, so I'm stuck just using the stove.

Answer (score 42):

Any modifier suggesting time would help: "That taco is too hot to eat *right now*" clearly implies that the heat is a function of temperature, not seasoning.

Comment: Unless the seasoning happens to be volatile... but even alcohol doesn't evaporate _that_ quickly.

Comment: "The food is _still too hot_" is a common instance of this this type of expression.

Answer (score 27):

As crude as it may sound, I like to make very spicy dishes and I frequently hear people use "...hot as in *spicy-hot* or *hot-hot*?"

Perhaps this is too anecdotal, but I would find it not uncomfortable or uncomprehensible for someone to specify the heat to which they refer using just the phrase *hot-hot*, even in the absence of the comparative *spicy-hot*.

Comment: Good point. I've often heard people say "Do you you mean spicy-hot or temperature-hot?" or similar phrases.

Comment: I hear it a lot too. And if someone said *"I like my soup hot-hot"* I'd take it for granted they were talking about temperature, even without the contrasting *"...but not too spicy-hot"*. For me, the repetition encourages interpreting the word in its *primary* sense, though I suppose some people might understand it to amplify the figurative meaning (*extra* spicy).

Answer (score 23):

What always works in my circle is "this food is high in thermal energy," but that might have limited appeal.

Comment: just give the exact temperature in kelvins then.

Comment: "Tea. Earl Grey. 353 Kelvins."  Just doesn't have the right ring to it, you know?

Comment: @fluffy I think that Kelvin, being a Lord himself, would have appreciated.

Comment: Reminds me of Tom Paris trying to get some tomato soup from a replicator just after he gets on Voyager (IIRC, may have been one of the alternate timeline episodes too). "Specify hot or chilled." "HOT! Hot, plain tomato soup!" ... "43 varieties and they still can't get plain tomato soup right..."

Comment: @fluffy - everyone knows you can get tea from a machine on a scapeship. At least not one made by the sirius cybernetics corp.

Answer (score 12):

This food is very warm⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠.

Comment: or even *scalding warm*, on need

Comment: @ZJR Scalding Warm sounds like an oxymoron. Scalding implies a great amount of heat, warm implies a minimal amount.

Comment: This is my solution, but a woman I know who is a lifetime resident of Colorado actually misses this distinction; I've heard her use the term "warm" to refer to food that is of medium spiciness.

Answer (score 7):

"Don't burn yourself, it's still hot."

Answer (score 5):

How about: This food is "burning" hot.

I learned how important it is not to translate idioms when I was in Germany. After interviewing a female candidate a colleague asked "What did you think of her?" I replied Sie ist sharf (She is sharp). He then asked me how I could possibly know that she was horny. Blushing, I explained my translation error.

Comment: English speakers learning Spanish are always told that although "caliente" means "hot", you must always use "cálido" if you are referring to a person being hot, because "caliente" has connotations. Of course, there is a t-shirt that says "My Spanish teacher is MUI CALIENTE"

Comment: I have had a niece refer to piquant food as burn-y/burning hot, but was referring to scovilles (and in one instance due to garlic) not thermal heat.

Comment: @slim Surely that must be *muy caliente*, unless the person’s surname (or maamname) should happen to be ‘Mui’. I do know such people.

Comment: No, "burning hot" could be idiomatically interpreted to mean "spicy" as well.  As a matter of fact, I've heard people talking about spicy food "setting their mouths on fire".

Comment: @RiceFlourCookies There actually something Quite Interesting going on there with the human nervous system, in which the mind equates the stimulus of capsaicin to that of heat. And yet nothing is damaged. Here’s [la entrada de Wikipedia sobre esto](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsaicina#Analg.C3.A9sico), which persumably you’ll be able to read in English again someday. :)

Answer (score 5):

My family says "oven hot".
But that is probably after just using the confusing "hot" first.

Answer (score 4):

Advice on what to do about the food being thermally hot would be hard to misinterpret: "You might need to give this a few minutes to cool".

Answer (score 4):

I would say

> hot to touch

or

> hot to the touch

Answer (score 3):

Good question! It's hard not to give a very clumsy answer.

I think you have to qualify the statement somehow. For example,

> Mind you don't burn yourself, it's hot

or

> It's hot, as in temperature

The only other way is to use a synonym of heat (blazing, scorching, searing), although you could probably argue that those could be used to describe spicy hot food too (although less likely).

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of a way to differentiate clearly using only one word, but you could take advantage of the fact that temperature will change over time and spice content will not and say something like "This food is still hot, be careful."

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, the food is **sizzling hot**, according to [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sizzling):

> very hot

Example from the same source:

> sizzling summer temperatures

Attribution: Definition of sizzling adjective from the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

"How can I unambiguously say that food is hot?" Unambiguously? Well, something like: "the temperature of the dish is too high for the dish to be safely consumed". :) But, how high is "too high" and how safe is "safe"?

I guess you would need to establish a context for a listener, if you cannot count on your content (i.e. tea can be hot in all cultures, but not spicy).

It is sometimes useful to introduce the "vocabulary" you intend to use, so your listeners know  that "hot" is related to temperature and "spicy" to taste.

Comment: warm ≠ piquant ≠ spicey

Answer (score 0):

I would describe the food as, 'hot, but not burning hot'. Or as, 'burning hot,' if it was. Or, if I didn't know, as, 'hot (I don't know if it's burning hot.)'.

Answer (score -1):

- Scoville (measure of piquance subject to a human panel of testers, relative)
- Temperature (measure of the mean kinetic energy of a sample, precise)

From that came the very popular "Damn, that's scoville, baby!" or "That is tempish!" in my mind.

In reality this will need contextual clarification for some time in the current cultural idioms.

We should start a movement on this one and you can lead it.

Comment: Downvotes for what? I love SO in general but the English language is fraught with illogical idiosyncratic unfit for justification. I am done with this topic.

Answer (score -1):

How about *heated*?

> Careful, that food is *heated*.

Answer (score -1):

You could also focus on the method of serving, for example: **careful, the plate is hot!** It's clear that you mean thermal heat because you don't eat the plate.

Comment: what is clear is that you mean the plate is hot, not necessarily that the food is; some restaurants actually keep plates (serving dishes) hot, ready for the food, which may or maynt be so hot.

Comment: @user it will inspire caution, which is ultimately what the question is about. Most plates aren't kept above 70 degrees C (that's non-American for 158 degrees F). Anyway, serving on a plate hotter than that might open one up to a lawsuit as we saw in [Liebeck v. McDonalds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liebeck_v._McDonald%27s_Restaurants) (that's the American way of complaining about restaurants). Now that I think of it, serving food that hot might inspire a lawsuit as well (similar to the Liebeck suit).

Answer (score -3):

..........'Over 70 degrees Celsius'.