# Order of adjectives: why is "This is a hot, tasty, Indian curry." wrong?

Tags: adjective-position

It seems that the correct form is "This is a tasty, hot, Indian curry."

I don't understand why you cant reorder "tasty" and "hot". It seems to me that they both reflect the gustatory sensation of the subject and  are not giving opinion.

Is "hot" always about the temperature (discussed in  [How to say that food is hot (temperature) without the listener thinking that I mean "spicy"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/55052/) ) and not about the capsaicinoids contents?

Comment: I did find this specific example here: http://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/courses/elc/Sample/Advanced/gs/gs_40_2.htm

Comment: It's misleading to suggest that *every* pair of adjectives has some predefined "correct" sequence. I can't put my finger on exactly why, but neither *tasty hot curry* nor *hot tasty curry* are particularly likely collocations in English (curries are often *hot*, but rarely *tasty*, and almost never both at once). But the relatively few written instances of, say, *hot tasty **soup*** are balanced by much the same number of *tasty hot soups*. Neither of which is any more "correct" than the other.

Comment: I disagree with the premise. The title sentence sounds perfectly fine to me (in AmE).

Comment: @FF--I don't see why you say that curries are often hot, but rarely tasty.  Here in the US, curries, can and often are both.  I'm not sure who'd buy them if they weren't tasty.

Comment: I'd eliminate the comma before "Indian", though.

Comment: If you consider *Indian curry* to be a kind of food, then the comma is intrusive. But if you take it to be one variety or origination of curry, then I see no problem with it. There is a difference between a *pale ale* and an *ale which happens to be pale in color*, and so it is one might distinguish an Indian from a Thai or Japanese curry.