# Spicy-hot and temperature-hot single-word-request?

Tags: single-word-requests

'Hot' has more than one meaning. Is there a separate word for hot when talking about spicy food supposed to temperature-hot? As it is awfully confusing when talking about Indian food. In Indian cooking food can be spicy with many spices but is not 'spicy-hot'. Masala Chai is spicy tea with no 'spicy-heat'! It is also served piping hot meaning the temperature is high.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70924/a-better-word-for-hot-spicy

Comment: You might talk about something being *highly spiced*.  That will not have any *hot* connotations.  Masala Chai is a *spiced* tea served hot.

Comment: Also related: [How to say that food is hot (temperature) without the listener thinking that I mean “spicy”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55052/how-to-say-that-food-is-hot-temperature-without-the-listener-thinking-that-i-m?rq=1)

Comment: For "temperature hot", I have heard people say "hot hot", as opposed to "spicy hot".

Comment: When we were living in Mexico during my first sabbatical, our family just borrowed the Spanish verb _picar_ 'to sting' and all its derivatives for the chemical "hot": _Pica mucho; picante; plenty pica,_ etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A better word for 'hot' (spicy)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70924/a-better-word-for-hot-spicy)