# Another way to say "hot" as in "hot peppers"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am making this sauce, which is extremely hot (as in hot peppers) that is being served cold (as in temperature). People who try it ask me what it is, so I say it is "cold hot sauce", which is a bit problematic, as the two are literal antonyms, even if not in the particular context.

So is there another world I could use for (extremely) hot that makes it clear it is indeed very hot? "Spicy" comes to mind but it is a big understatement. Anything else?

Comment: Did you check a thesaurus for "hot" and "spicy"?

Comment: 'Peppery'. But this too is polysemous.

Comment: There is some pepper in it, but most of the hotness is due to garlic actually. And no, I don't think that "garlic sauce" gives credit to how hot it is, as all the garlic sauces I've tried are a tiny fraction of the hotness.

Comment: related: [**A better word for 'hot' (spicy)?**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70924/a-better-word-for-hot-spicy) and [**Difference between “spicy” and “hot”**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50080/difference-between-spicy-and-hot)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - piquance is also present in my native language, however it implies "moderately spicy" not "you really don't want to eat a spoonful of it on its own".

Comment: Extremely hot? "Fire in the hole" :)

Comment: You could use a synonym for "cold" instead: "chilled"

Comment: You could say your dish is served cold but is high on the Scoville heat scale.

Comment: Unfortunately if “most of the heat comes from the garlic” it is not really that hot.  In general though, Hot sauces are widely understood to be “spicy hot” not temperature hot, and there should be no ambiguity in refering to it as a hot sauce. Just be prepared for people to say, “you call this hot?!?” ;-)

Comment: @Airymouse - the scoville heat unit measures capsaicin.  the heat from onions and garlic comes from allicin and is measured on the pyruvate scale. I was trying to find a site that tried to relate the two but I was not successful.  I would imagine it couldn’t be higher than a couple thousand at most though.

Comment: @Jim - you couldn't be more off. You are probably thinking "store brand garlic sauce" which barely has any garlic in it. There can't be a real comparison because it is a different kind of hot, but after a spoon of that sauce, cayenne pepper comes in sweet and actually quench the fire, and cayenne pepper is listed as 30-50k. I'd give that sauce the equivalent of at least around 100k-150k, although those things may vary from person to person, depending on taste buds and such.

Comment: @ddriver - maybe.  I was making my judgement based on having eaten raw garlic and raw hot peppers of various kinds and to me the garlic doesn’t come close to the heat of the peppers. I don’t buy store garlic sauces.

Comment: @Jim - garlic varies in hotness just as much as peppers do, it is not just "one garlic". Most people don't like extra pungent food, which would explain why most of the cultivated garlic is rather soft.

Answer (score 4):

How about **fiery**?

MW:

> [**fiery**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fiery): hot like a fire: "the fiery taste of red pepper"

It's hard to imagine anything hotter in your mouth than fire.