# Word for "the state of having eaten spicy food"

Tags: single-word-requests

How do I say that my mouth is feeling very hot from the spicy food that I ate?

What word should I say?

Comment: That’s quite a serious constraint: that it be but one single word for that entire idea, that it end in *-ed*, and that it be usable as a predicate.

Comment: Hi @Mark Gabriel. To make it clear that you are referring to your mouth, you probably need to say something like 'my mouth is on fire' or 'my mouth is burning'.

Comment: Inflammatory ??

Comment: Language isn't logical. There's not necessarily a word to fill in every conceptual spot, for every sense.  Note that there are no such patterns (as you request for any of the other tastes (bitter, sweet etc). Also, even if there were such a word, it is very possible that you just don't say it that way in English. To get across your idea however, you would say things like what @JulieCarter suggested, the food had that property, not really your mouth.

Comment: Isn't your mouth *numb*?

Comment: @RegDwigнt: I don't know about *your* mouth, but mine definitely is *not* numb when I have eaten very spicy food!

Comment: This is so similar it might be the same: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148117/one-word-phrase-to-describe-the-reaction-when-you-eat-a-very-spicy-hot-food

Comment: The dupe you're trying to close has a word in Indonesian for *pungency* (that's spelled an awful lot like *capsaicin*...). Agreed, it's a dupe. Thanks for the DV on my answer, whoever that was.

Answer (score 0):

**Inflamed** is the best I can find. You ate wasabi and now you mouth is **inflamed**. Although people more typically just say that their mouth is on fire or is burning.

Answer (score 0):

i think the best term to use to describe this feeling would be "spiced". Such as, "Bro that hot pepper made me so spiced!"

Comment: Do you have any examples of this usage?

Answer (score -1):

> **Pungency** is the condition of having a strong, sharp smell or taste that is often so strong that it is unpleasant. Pungency is the technical term used by scientists to refer to the characteristic of food commonly referred to as spiciness or hotness and sometimes heat, which is found in foods such as chili peppers. [...]
>
> The terms "pungent" and "pungency" are rarely used in colloquial speech but are preferred by scientists as they eliminate the potential ambiguity arising from use of the words "hot" and "spicy", which can also refer to temperature and the presence of spices, respectively. –[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pungency)

pun·gent /ˈpənjənt/ adjective

> : having a sharply strong taste or smell. *"the pungent smell of frying onions"* –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=pungent&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

*The capsaicin in those peppers left my mouth feeling very **pungent**.*

> [[Capsaicin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsaicin)] is an **irritant** for mammals –Wiki

*No thanks, my mouth is still **irritated** from the last horderves.*

---

What you'll probably say: WATER!

What you really need: milk.

> Milk contains casein, a fat-loving compound that binds with spicy capsaicin oil and then washes it away. –[discovery.com](http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/mythbusters-database/cure-milk-hot-chilies/)

---

No single word colloquially encompasses the internationally understood action of panting and fanning your open mouth.